# Excel - Open a named userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

Sure this is very basic, I had userforms that I had not named and I called these by using `UserForm1.Show`. Now I have named these eg. ProgressBar.

I call this one by `UserForms.Add("ProgressBar").Show vbModeless`

But i cant figure out how to make this bit work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'With UserForms("ProgressBar")
With Me
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
End With
End Sub
```

How should I call these forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would just be With ProgressBar as opposed to With UserForms("ProgressBar") wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks Dan, what about my statement to open the userform? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I would have thought it would just be ProgressBar.show vbModeless